# Accessing data of a file from Azure blob storage to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

I want to access data of a file from Azure blob storage to a variable.

The below code which I am using reads data of a file from Azure blob storage to a local file. I want to read it into a variable. Is it possible to do it?

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess

accountName='user123'
accountKey='Pass@12345'
CONTAINER_NAME='development'
blobName='4567/dummyFile.txt'
file_path='C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\testFile.txt' # local file in which the content from blob will be written


block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=accountName, account_key=accountKey)

# to access content from azure blob storage to local file
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,blobName,file_path)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Python SDK for Azure Storage`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py) provides 3 helper methods for that purpose:

1. **`get_blob_to_stream`**: This method will download the blob and store the contents in a `stream`. Use this method if you want to use a `stream` type variable.
2. **`get_blob_to_bytes`**: This method will download the blob and store the contents in a `byte array`. Use this method if you want to use a `byte array` type variable.
3. **`get_blob_to_text`**: This method will download the blob and store the contents in a `string`. Use this method if you want to use a `string` type variable. Please use this method only if you know the blob contents are string. If the contents of a blob are binary (e.g. an image file), use other two method.

Comment: Thank you, I used the following and it worked
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(CONTAINER_NAME,blobName).content
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(CONTAINER_NAME,blobName).content

just wondering when to use bytes vs text

Comment: Updated my answer. You would want to use `get_blob_to_text` only if you know the blob's content is text. If the blob's content is binary (say an image), storing that as text will make the blob unusable.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for version 12.8.1 of the azure-storage-blob package. The BlockBlobService class doesn't appear to be supported in the newer versions.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient    # azure-storage-blob 12.8.1

connection_string = " "
local_file_name = "example.txt"
container_name = "example_container"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(local_file_name)
my_blob = blob_client.download_blob().readall() # read blob content as string

print(my_blob)
```